# How to add space between components that comes from a mapping function?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add some buttons with a title that is inside every position of an array (for exaMple the first button have its title in the content of the array in the position 0), that is the reason i am using a map function and it works but... i can not add space between each button

it looks like this:
[image]
THIS IS WHERE THE MAPPING FUNCTION IS CALLED:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <View style={{
       flexDirection: 'row',
       justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    {mapping()}
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

THIS IS THE FUNCTION:

```
function mapping() {
  const horas = ["6:30-7:30", "7:30-8:30", "7:30-8:30"...]
  const mappeo = horas.map((i) => {
    return (
        <Button
            title={i}
            type="outline"
            style={{ padding:10}}/>
          )
  }
  )
  return (mappeo)
}
```

So how can i separate the buttons?

Answer (score 2):

How about using margin. Padding are used for content inside a container and margins are used for applying margins or spaces outside the container.

**Try this**

```
function mapping() {
  const horas = ["6:30-7:30", "7:30-8:30", "7:30-8:30"...]
  const mappeo = horas.map((i) => {
    return (
        <Button
            title={i}
            type="outline"
            style={{ padding:10, marginHorizontal:10}}/>
          )
  }
  )
  return (mappeo)
}
```

Comment: it worked! the problem was that the Button component i am using is from react native elements and to style the button the prop is "buttonStyle" not "style"

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

add 'marginHorizontal' to your button like below:

```
function mapping() {
  const horas = ["6:30-7:30", "7:30-8:30", "7:30-8:30"...]
  const mappeo = horas.map((i) => {
    return (
        <Button
            title={i}
            type="outline"
            style={{ padding:10, marginHorizontal: 5 }}/>
          )
  }
  )
  return (mappeo)
}
```